# Configuring format of axis for time delta in jquery flot

Tags: jquery, plot, flot

I'm trying to configure the y-axis of jquery flot to show time interval in months:days:hours:minutes:seconds format. Here is my plot options

```
options = {
    xaxis: {
        mode: "time"
    },
    series: {
        lines: {show: true, lineWidth: 2},
        hadowSize: 0
    },
    yaxis: {
        mode: "time",
        timeformat: "%m:%d:%H:%M:%S"
    },
    points: {show: true},
    legend:  {show: true, position: 'nw'}
    }
}
```

I have a dataset of points of timestamps in milliseconds. Dates on x-axis are okay, but on y-axis
something is wrong. How can I fix it?

Comment: What happens on the y-axis?

Comment: @DNS for example, it parse timstamp 3513085000 like 04:01:04:00:00 (m:d:H:M:S), but actually it's around 40 days, e.g. 1 month and 9 days

Comment: @DNS here is link to my [plot](http://www.flickr.com/photos/65651819@N02/9157205665/) and here is part of my dataset                                                                 [[1372118400000.0, 3513085000.0],
 [1372032000000.0, 6126615000.0],
 [1371945600000.0, 7943383000.0],
 [1371859200000.0, 8161095000.0],
 [1371772800000.0, 10791291000.0]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flot doesn't support time deltas; only absolute dates.  You're doing two different things on the X and Y axes, and only the absolute dates in the x-axis are supported.